# How to find the pde arising from following surface?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

For $w=w(x,y)$, How to find the pde arising from following surface?
$$xyw=f(x+y+w)$$

I can't calculate $w_x$ and $w_y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f'$ denotes $\dfrac{df(t)}{dt}$

$$xyw=f(x+y+w)$$

$$yw+xyw_x=(1+w_x)f'\;;f'=\dfrac{yw+xyw_x}{1+w_x}$$

$$xw+xyw_y=(1+w_y)f'\;;f'=\dfrac{xw+xyw_y}{1+w_y}$$

$$\dfrac{yw+xyw_x}{1+w_x}=\dfrac{xw+xyw_y}{1+w_y}$$

$$(yw+xyw_x)(1+w_y)=(xw+xyw_y)(1+w_x)$$

$$yw+xyw_x+yww_y+xyw_xw_y=xw+xyw_y+xww_x+xyw_xw_y$$

$$(xy-xw)w_x-(xy-yw)w_y=(x-y)w$$

**Check**

$$\dfrac{dx}{xy-xw}=\dfrac{-dy}{xy-yw}=\dfrac{dw}{(x-y)w}$$

$$\dfrac{dx+dy}{xy-xw-xy+yw}=\dfrac{dw}{(x-y)w}$$

$$\dfrac{dx+dy}{-(x-y)w}=\dfrac{dw}{(x-y)w}\;;dx+dy=-dw\;;x+y=-w+c_1$$

$$c_1=x+y+z$$

$$\dfrac{ydx}{y(xy-xw)}=\dfrac{-xdy}{x(xy-yw)}=\dfrac{dw}{(x-y)w}$$

$$\dfrac{ydx+xdy}{y(xy-xw)-x(xy-yw)}=\dfrac{dw}{(x-y)w}$$

$$\dfrac{ydx+xdy}{-(x-y)xy-xyw+xyw}=\dfrac{dw}{(x-y)w}$$

$$\dfrac{ydx+xdy}{-(x-y)xy}=\dfrac{dw}{(x-y)w}\;;\dfrac{ydx+xdy}{xy}=\dfrac{-dw}{w}$$

$$\ln\vert xy\vert+k=-\ln\vert w\vert\;;c_2=xyw$$

$$xyw=f(x+y+z)$$